# Inline assembler: Pass a constant

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

I have the following problem: I want to use the following assembler code from my C source files using inline assembler:

```
.word 1
```

The closest I've gotten is using this inline assembler code:

```
asm(".word %0\n": : "i"(1));
```

However, this results in the following code in the generated assembler file:

```
.word #1
```

So I need a way to pass a constant that is known at compile time without adding the '#' in front of it. Is this possible using inline assembler?

**Edit:**

To make it more clear why I need this, this is how it will be used:

```
#define LABELS_PUT(b) asm(".word %0\n": : "i"((b)));

int func(void) {
    LABELS_PUT(1 + 2);

    return 0;
}
```

I can't use ".word 1" because the value will be different every time the macro LABELS_PUT is called.

Comment: RTFM. What's wrong with `asm(".word 1\n": : :);`? Please read the documentation and/or a tutorial.

Comment: That's for ARM?  Is this something you can't do more easily with a separately-compiled .s?

Comment: I've edited the question to make clear why I can't use ".word 1"

Comment: You can't pass a constant by inlining a `.word` directive.  You're just inserting invalid instructions into the function. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your macro has a `;` at the end.  So it's a whole statement, not just an expression.  Don't do that.

A `.word` mixed in with the code of your function is usually going to be an illegal instruction, isn't it?  Are you actually planning to run this binary?

---

You should be able to get the preprocessor to [stringify your macro parameter](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html), and let string-concatenation join it up.  Then the assembler can evaluate `1+2`.

```
#define LABELS_PUT(b) asm(".word " #b  "\n")


LABELS_PUT(1+2);   // becomes:
asm(".word " "1+2" "\n");
```

---

There's also https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers, some of which might work for other architectures:

```
asm (".word %c0" : : "i" (b))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks very promising. I will look into the two options.

Answer (score -1):

In GCC you can do it like this:

```
asm __volatile__ (".word 0x1");
```

If you are using Visual Studio then you can try:

```
some_word: _asm{_emit 1000b}
```

It will pass into code word constant 1000b

You can get access with label some_word

Comment: The `volatile` is [implicit for GNU C asm statements with no outputs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile).  That's why I didn't use it in my answer.