# inline ARMv7-M assembly code into c using gcc and macros

Tags: gcc, arm, c-preprocessor, inline-assembly

I have this code that works fine:

```c
void function( void )
{
    __asm volatile
    (
        "   ldr r3, .ADDRESS            \n"
        "   mov r2, %0                  \n"
        "   str r2, [r3, %1]            \n"
        ".ADDRESS:  .word 0x401C4000    \n"
        :: "i" (1<<17), "i" (16)
    );
}
```

But to declare `.ADDRESS` I used the magic number 0x401C4000. I actually have a macro for this.

For Example:

```c
#define ADDR_BASE 0x401C4000
#define ADDR ((void *)ADDR_BASE)

void function( void )
{
    __asm volatile
    (
        "   ldr r3, .ADDRESS            \n"
        "   mov r2, %0                  \n"
        "   str r2, [r3, %1]            \n"
        ".ADDRESS:    .word %2          \n"
        :: "i" (1<<17), "i" (16), "i" (ADDR)
    );
}
```

That doesn't build.

How can I use a macro in this case?

Comment: Did you intend to put the `.word` where it will execute as machine code right after the `str` instruction?  Also, you know you could ask for a number or address already in a register, right?  If your only use of of it is going to be loading or moving it into a register, you're just making things less efficient by not letting the compiler potentially optimize after inlining this function into a loop or something.  Also, you forgot clobber declarations on R2 and R3, and `"memory"` if there's a C object there, which would be unnecessary if you avoided inline asm entirely and used `volatile int*`.

Comment: @PeterCordes this you must consider it only an example of the problem that I have. Suppose that I have to modify this function https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/main/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.c#L439 . As you can see I can't write it in c, but instead I need to inline those 3 instructions in a couple of points

Comment: If you have some instructions a compiler can't generate, yes that's what inline asm is for. 
 But usually you want *only* those instructions inside your asm template, telling the compiler what you want in registers before they run. Nothing's stopping you from reducing this to `asm ("str %0, [%2, %1]" :: "r" (1<<17), "i" (16), "r" (ADDR) : "memory");` with register constraints for the 2 things you need in registers, so your asm template doesn't write any registers and thus doesn't need any register clobbers.  And don't have `.word` in the path of execution without .pushsection/.popsection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the edit below. I'm only leaving this first solution as an example of what you shouldn't do.

---

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35325488/552247) where a solution is given to my same problem, but it involves x86.
I wanted to try it anyway, and it works.

Then use `%c2` instead of `%2`, as shown here:

```c
#define ADDR_BASE 0x401C4000
#define ADDR ((void *)0x401C4000)

void function( void )
{
    __asm volatile
    (
        "   ldr r3, .ADDRESS            \n"
        "   mov r2, %0                  \n"
        "   str r2, [r3, %1]            \n"
        ".ADDRESS:   .word %c2          \n"
        :: "i" (1<<17), "i" (16), "i" (ADDR): "r2", "r3", "memory"
    );
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The solution I suggested above may not work by seeing the generated code:

```
  20                function:
  21                    @ Function supports interworking.
  22                    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
  23                    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
  24                    @ link register save eliminated.
  25 0000 04B02DE5      str fp, [sp, #-4]!
  26 0004 00B08DE2      add fp, sp, #0
  27                    .syntax divided
  28                @ 6 "test.c" 1
  29 0008 04309FE5         ldr r3, .ADDRESS            
  30 000c 0228A0E3     mov r2, #131072                  
  31 0010 102083E5     str r2, [r3, #16]            
  32 0014 00401C40  .ADDRESS:   .word 1075593216          
  33                
  34                @ 0 "" 2
  35                    .arm
  36                    .syntax unified
  37 0018 0000A0E1      nop
  38 001c 00D08BE2      add sp, fp, #0
  39                    @ sp needed
  40 0020 04B09DE4      ldr fp, [sp], #4
  41 0024 1EFF2FE1      bx  lr
```

You can see at line 32 the symbol `.ADDRESS` has been issued, but it is surrounded by code, and there is no instruction to skip it. I believe that it can be attempted to be executed as if it were an instruction.

Maybe a better solution, suggested by Peter, is

```c
#define ADDR_BASE 0x401C4000
#define ADDR ((void *)0x401C4000)

void function( void )
{
    __asm volatile
    (
    "str %0, [%2, %1]"
    :: "r" (1<<17), "i" (16), "r" (ADDR) : "memory"
    );
}
```

Comment: Since the goal of this site is to archive questions and answers that are useful to future users, could you please fix the bugs in the code you've posted, specifically the missing clobbers?  That concept is hard enough for new programmers to get right without being flooded by incorrect code across the Internet.

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited by adding the clobbers. I think I wrote the right thing. The reference I took the example from didn't have them.

Comment: Removed my downvote since the only remaining bug is the showstopper where `.word` is right there in the `.text` section, and gets executed as instruction bytes.  People won't copy this and think it works when it's actually unsafe; it will very likely just crash.  (Unless the `.word` decodes as an instruction that messes up other registers).  A better solution by far would be to ask the compiler for `"r"(ADDR)` instead of materializing it yourself, then you can let it pick the register and not need a clobber. And let it schedule the load earlier.